# pandas concat dictionary problem with too many indices

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, concatenation

I am trying to concat a bunch of data frames which I placed into a dictionary. The following is my code:

```
for file in filepath:   
    df[i] = pd.read_csv(file)
    df[i]['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[i]['Date'].astype(str), format='%m/%d/%Y')        
    i += 1
    count += 1
    print(file)
    
new = pd.concat([d.set_index('Date') for d in df.values()], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

I get the following error: `Shape of passed values is (1924, 55), indices imply (1904, 55)` is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: you are trying to `concat` side-by-side rather than one on top of the other. is that intentional? if not then set `axis=0`. If yes, what do you want to do with the mismatched number of rows between the dataframes?

Comment: I am trying to combine the data side by side so it just attaches new columns based on date, when I do axis=0 I get an empty dataframe. Anything that the dataframes don't have in common to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, what you want is to join (merge) the dataframes not concat them. Without having the dfs handy (for your next question review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please) I cannot test the below, but roughly this is what you want to do

```
new = None
for file in filepath:   
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str), format='%m/%d/%Y')        
    df.set_index('Date', inplace = True)
    if new is None:
        new = df
    else:
        new = new.join(df)
```